# SSRS and PDF export issue

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have a problem when trying to add page breaks in my SSRS report. It works fine in the view mode, but when trying to export the report to PDF format, an extra blank page appears. Any idea why this happens ?

Comment: The problem is probably in the page margin. maybe the report is larger/longer than the pdf page.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2005 Reporting Services, the ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace option is not available because the white space is automatically omitted.

In SSRS 2008 or higher, click on the yellow space outside the report body area and press F4 to open the Properties pane.  You can find the **ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace** option in the Report Properties pane.

Reference:
[ConsumeContainerWhitespace property to remove blank space in SSRS 2008 report](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/115/posts/11153/consumecontainerwhitespace-property-to-remove-blank-space-in-ssrs-2008-report.aspx)